# Equalizer installation problem (Lumia 520)

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-520, equalizer

Recently, I had to reset my 520 due to some technical problems. While updating the system apps, **Equalizer** keeps giving me error. *Now, I know that,this app cant be installed on my 520 due to hardware limitations*, i know that.

But is there any way i could cancel this, because every time i head to the store, its present there, it doesn't update, but it keeps on showing in downloads list. Is there a way to remove this from the downloads list?

Answer (score 1):

If you can pause it, pause and cancel it.

Else go to *Settings->System->Storage->Phone Storage->Apps*. Uninstall Equalizer from there. Open store and check for updates.

Now restart the phone. After some time(for it took more than a day) reinstall the Equalizer app it will install without asking for hardware limitations. You can find the Equalizer app in My library.

I faced the same error and it worked.

Comment: i couldnt find equalizer in both phone's n sd's storage! :(

Comment: @RamRaj you said you were updating the app. Are you sure that the equaliser is installed? Go to Settings->Extras and confirm that it is installed. If it is installed then it should be on the list of installed apps in Phone storage.

Comment: am sorry, its not installed, you know, the first time we install OS, we need some installs and updates, right! thats what am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem on my Lumia 535: unable to download Equaliser, being informed of error. But Equaliser is known in extras and info as AUDIO no wonder I couldn't find it in either apps, on SD Card or This Device Storage. Yes, there it was on the SD Card as Audio, I needed to save space on This Device, because the Lumia 535 has only 8g storage.

Simply hold on audio icon in SD Card storage, then move it to This Device, go to Store, check for updates and install Equaliser.

Answer (score 0):

Lumia 520 does not support sound Equilizer feature. I know there is app called Equilizer but when you update it the app gets change to audio settings and it comes under your settings app. And when you open it, you won't see any Equilizer. There is only one toggle of to change the settings of phone silent. 
[image: Lumia 520 Audio settings.]